# Python Logging in Datadog All Error Status

Tags: python, logging, datadog

I do not understand why DataDog is showing all statuses as errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avlNv.png)

The script is pretty straightforward.

```
import logging
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

logger = logging.getLogger()

logHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter()
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)

logger.info('this is info')
logger.warning('this is warning')
logger.error('this is error')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the Python standard logging module defaulting to use `stderr` as its output stream. From the `StreamHandler` constructor documentation

*Returns a new instance of the StreamHandler class. If stream is specified, the instance will use it for logging output; **otherwise, sys.stderr will be used.***

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler